# Why can't I call upon a variable from Main method inside of another method in C#?

Tags: c#

Sorry for all of the confusion, this is my first post and I'm still learning C# and proper Stack Overflow etiquette. I have a variable, "playerDamage", that the user defined through Console.ReadLine() in the Main method.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static class Globals
  {
    public static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int boarHP = 5;
    public static int boarDamage = 3;
    public static int boarEvasion = 3;
  }
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
//
Console.WriteLine("You look into a barrel to see a short SWORD hilt poking out, a DAGGER stabbed into the side, and at the very bottom there is a BOOK. Which one do you claim?\n");
string weapon = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
Console.WriteLine("\n");
int playerDamage = 1;
switch (weapon)
{
  case "SWORD":
  playerDamage += 5;
  break;
  case "DAGGER":
  playerDamage += 2;
  break;
  case "BOOK":
  playerDamage += 4;
  break;
}
  
      }
      static void CombatVsBoar() {
    Console.WriteLine("ATTACK | INVENTORY");
    string action = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (action == "ATTACK")
    {
      if (Globals.boarEvasion >= Globals.rnd.Next(1, 5))
      {
        Globals.boarHP -= Main.playerDamage;
      }
    }
      }
}
```

I receive the error message:

> main.cs(97,32): error CS0023: The `.' operator cannot be applied to operand of type` method group'

I'm getting this message from the line

> Globals.boarHP -= Main.playerDamage;

and I think that's because the variable playerDamage was defined in the Main method and I'm trying to call on it in my new CombatVsBoar method. Is there a way for me to access this variable in multiple methods, while still having it be defined by the user in a roleplaying context?
I hope this is enough code to understand the context of my problem.

Comment: So you are trying to call a local variable in Main from another method? Cant be done, make the variable an instance member or static to the class

Comment: _"I'm trying to call on a variable that I defined in the Main method"_ -- that's not how local variables work. A method name is not a valid source for a variable. If you want methods to share variables, they must be declared _outside_ any method. See duplicate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I just edited my original post to include this, but the variable that I'm trying to use is defined by the user through Console.ReadLine() . I can't declare it outside of any method if I need the user to define it, right?

Comment: Just to let you know.  When you create a question, you need to provide enough information for the reader to unambiguously understand what you are talking about.  Everyone is assuming that `Main` in your code is where the error occurs and that it refers to the `Main()` method you have defined elsewhere.  A better version of your question would include a comment like `// << Line 97, error here` to let us know where the error is.  It would also include your `Main()` method (or enough of us to understand things)

Comment: Without seeing a proper [mcve], including the `Main()` method you refer to, it's impossible to know what you mean. Also, variables aren't declared at runtime by any means, never mind by a call to `Console.ReadLine()`, so it's not clear what you mean by that either. Your post also doesn't explain which statement actually generates the error, and the statement can't be inferred from the error message, because there's not enough information in the error message. So that's unclear as well. But the bottom line is: if you want to use a variable in two or more methods, it cannot be a local variable.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for sharing that link, I'm brand new to Stack Overflow and I'm still learning the etiquette for this site. I shared enough code to reproduce my issue.